# How can i synchronize a temp table and a normal table?

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization, cron

i have a shop and the products are stored in a csv file. The csv file are imported by a cronjob in a temp table. my problem is to synchronize the temp table with the normal table (productive). some rows must be updated, added or deleted. I can't import the CSV file in the productive table because the intervall must be every 30 minutes.

Does anybody knows a program for this problem? For windows and mysql 5.0.x?

greetings!

Comment: yes, how can i synchronize the two tables

Comment: Two easy steps: 1) define rules. 2) write code.

Comment: Please post the layout of your tables and of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could just replace the original table with the temporary table:

```
DROP TABLE `ORIGINAL_TABLE`;
RENAME TABLE `TEMPORARY_TABLE` TO `ORIGINAL_TABLE`;
```

Or even safer...back up the original table first...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `BACKUP_TABLE`;
CREATE TABLE `BACKUP_TABLE` LIKE `ORIGINAL_TABLE`;
INSERT INTO `BACKUP_TABLE` SELECT * FROM `ORIGINAL_TABLE`;
DROP TABLE `ORIGINAL_TABLE`;
RENAME TABLE `TEMPORARY_TABLE` TO `ORIGINAL_TABLE`;
```

Comment: If that's the case then it would be time to start writing some code to update the table... ;)